# How can I send a ColdFusion XML Document to .NET as System.Xml.XmlElement?

Tags: .net, xml, coldfusion

I am working on a SAML SSO implementation using ColdFusion 8 and the ComponentSpace SAML2 .NET library.

I need to pass a value of type System.Xml.XmlElement to one of the .NET class constructors, but when I try to send a ColdFusion XMLDocument or XMLElement value, I get the error:

```
Unable to find a constructor for class ComponentSpace.SAML2.Protocols.SAMLResponse that accepts parameters of type ( coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeList ).
```

How can I pass a valid XmlElement value to the .NET class constructor starting with a ColdFusion XML variable?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert the ColdFusion XML String to an XML Element using `System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString)` (although now the class constructor won't accept it, but that's another issue).